# Google Apps Script -- Create Filter Timing out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that has 18000 rows and 27 columns, so a little under 500K rows. There are many formula derived columns in there . Some columns are derived based on other derived columns. All of this is working fine.

I want to filter the rows based on the value in three columns. The values in that column are either 0 or 1, so pretty simple. Below is the code and the error i am getting is Timeout like this :

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document
> with id 1NoBj4H7ZpLYJzDSXRfFaMnbHbxtp214vnL.

```html
function applyFilter(){  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var filterCriteria=SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(['1']).build();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1, lastRow, lastCol);
  var filteredRange = range.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(24,filterCriteria).getRange();
  //.setColumnFilterCriteria(25,filterCriteria).setColumnFilterCriteria(27, filterCriteria)
}
```

As you can see I even tried with setting the filter on 1 column and even then it failed. I am using the range as recommended , when I do it manually from the UI, it is able to filter in a matter of a second.

Update :

My intention is to have this act as a filter view, however none of my attempts are helping me to achieve that.

I took your idea and tried to copy the filtered results on to a new sheet  using this code

```html
function applyFilter(){  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var filterCriteria=SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberEqualTo(1).build();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1, lastRow, lastCol);
  //var filteredRange = range.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(24,filterCriteria).setColumnFilterCriteria(25,filterCriteria).setColumnFilterCriteria(27, filterCriteria).getRange();
  var filteredRows = range.getValues().filter(function(row){return (row[23] == 1 && row[24] == 1 && row[26] == 1);});
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(filteredRows);
  var filteredSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('filteredData');
  if(filteredSheet != null) { 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(filteredSheet);
  }
  filteredSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(); 
  filteredSheet.setName("filteredData"); 
  filteredSheet.appendRow(sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lastCol).getValues()[0]);
  filteredRows.forEach(function(r,i){
       filteredSheet.appendRow(r);
  });
  
}
```

This is slow but it worked.

Comment: I took the same script but instead of 18000 lines, I made my worksheet 1000 lines and ran the function and it took some time but it worked.  So I am guessing the way I am filtering is not the right way for a range of this size.

Comment: Try doing the filtering in an array.  It may still take some time.  18K lines is a lot.  I'd consider moving to a database.

Comment: I understand the general concept of filter and I assume you are referring to taking a range (as a two dimensional array) and applying a filter which should result into a new array. But how would we make it show only those rows and when you turn off the filter, show all the rows ? 

Any example there would help

Comment: I have this code  which will bring me the rows, but how do I only show these rows ? 


var filteredRows = range.getValues().filter(function(row){return row[23] == 1 && row[24] == 1 && row[26] == 1});

Comment: What are the questions that you wish to answer from the data?

Comment: My intention is to have this act as a filter view, however none of my attempts are helping me to achieve that.

Comment: I can certainly understand that you would want to filter you data because I personally wouldn't want to mess with 18K lines of data on a spreadsheet.  But these are the kinds of questions we answer here.